# In sharepoint, how to redirect to a pop window?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

There is a button in a pop window, I need click it to redirect to another pop window ? How can we achieve that?

Comment: You have tagged two different versions of sharepoint, so I removed the version-specific tags.

Comment: Good, Thanks! I Just wanna draw as many people as possible to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it as follows,

1. Add following script on the page.

   `<script type="text/javascript">
        function openDialog(tUrl, tTitle) {
            var options = {
                url: tUrl,
                title: tTitle
            };
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
        }
    </script>`
2. Call the function on a button or link click as follows

   `<a href="#" onclick="openDialog('Page.aspx','Page Title');">Show Modal Dialog</a>`

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my situation:**

I click the **Title** of a **SPListItem**, it pop up a custom **aspx** page I wrote, a window. There is asp **button** in the window, when I click it, I wish it redirect to another custom aspx page, in the same pop window. See it below,

[image: how it works]

Actually it's very simple, in the **Button Event Function**:

`protected void Edit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)`

We wrote 2 lines of code, it will do the job:

```
string url = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/_Layouts/TestPrj/test.aspx?List=********************&ID=*";
SPUtility.Redirect(url, SPRedirectFlags.Default, HttpContext.Current);
```

Really, I'm not kidding!